# rails 3 heroku sendgrid contact us

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sendgrid

Has anyone got a good tutorial or a gem to allow me to send emails via a contact form using sendgrid on heroku, i have the basic sendgrid set up and working as i am using exception notifications successfully.

Robbie Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback guys, in the end i followed this blog post and managed to get it working great - http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/

Answer (score 2):

If your Sendgrid/Heroku setup is working, [this tutorial on ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) should get you going!

Comment: How do i tie a simple contact form to Action Mailer though?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form - easy peasy mail forms!